# Possible number of collisions in a hashing function with constant message size

Tags: cryptography, hash, sha, md5

Jumping to conclusions from my [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123334/shouldnt-multiple-images-always-exist-even-in-most-powerful-hashing-algorithm), can we predict possible number of collisions for a given message in a given hashing algorithm.

Say I am using SHA-1 which outputs 160 characters string, and my input string is 161 characters, so does that mean each of my 161 character message has at most unlimited collisions and atleast 10 collisions/pre-images each of 161 characters. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I got 2 words for you: rainbow tables

Comment: There is an unlimited number of possible collisions (i.e. images leading to the same hash value) because there is an unlimited number of images and a limited number of hash values. To get a limit on the number of collisions you have to do some restrictions on the possible images, like size. But this is not really visible from your question. If you assume that all possible inputs you check for collision have all the same size of 161 then please say this more explicit in your question.

Comment: yes offcourse! i mean for constant message size, updated question as well as description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I am using SHA-1 which outputs 160 characters string, and my input string is 161 characters, so does that mean each of my 161 character message has at most unlimited collisions and at least 10 collisions/pre-images each of 161 characters. Is my understanding correct?

No.

First it cannot have unlimited collisions since the number of messages with 161 characters is limited itself. This means even for the worst hash algorithm which maps everything to a constant hash value there will be only 256^161 images mapping to the same hash value (assuming character is an octet).

Also there does not need to be any collisions at all for a given hash value and it is not even guaranteed there is one image within your set for each possible hash value.

What you can say is that you will get **on average** 10 images mapping to the same hash value. And with a good cryptographic hash like SHA-1 you will also get only a small deviation from this average.